# Remove unwanted instance of LibreOffice 7.5

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice, duplicate

after a regular update of the system (Ubuntu 22), I now have two installations of LibreOffice. Actually, only one shows up, the one I originally installed (7.3):

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libreoffice | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
ii liblibreoffice-java 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-base-core 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-calc 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-common 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-core 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-draw 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-gnome 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-gtk3 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-help-common 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-help-en-us 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-impress 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-java-common 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-math 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-ogltrans 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-pdfimport 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-style-breeze 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-style-colibre 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-style-elementary 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-style-yaru 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
ii libreoffice-writer 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
```

But on the application GUI there is also 7.5:
[image]

[image]

How can I selectively remove the redundant version 7.5?

Thank you

Comment: The libreoffice snap package is version 7.5.1.2, so I guess that's what you want to remove. `snap remove libreoffice` is what you need to run in this case.

Comment: yes, I think that was the problem. I now have only one installation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To remove unwanted 7.5 version of libreoffice try :
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice7.5*

It will remove all packages and dependances.

For me it worked.